# Error in code: python3 JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that I am trying to load to python but for whatever reason, yields the error, "python3 JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".

Here is my code:

```
def extract():
   with open (file, 'r') as f:
      data = json.load(f)
   print (data)
```

The format of the JSON file is

```
{
  "question" : {
    "0cGufvFVCR" : {
      "answer" : "___",
      "date" : "___",
      "email" : "___",
      "que" : "___"
```

print(repr(f.read())) yields a string in the format '{\n "question" : {\n "0cGufvFVCR" : {\n "answer" : 100,\n "date" : "Mar 26, 2020",\n "

Comment: It's not the valid json.

Comment: hey - what does it mean to not be valid json? when i use f.read it prints fine but as a string, however the file is in json/dictionary format.

Comment: As @snakecharmerb said, it is possible there are invisible characters at the start of the file, which the JSON parser is complaining about, which is why we want to see the output of `repr`.

Comment: You've `"answer": ___` in your json file which is not valid. You should instead have `"answer": "___"`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: It is more than likely `___` is a placeholder — presumably, the file has something that is not `___`. Numbers, booleans etc do not need quoting. This is not the issue being asked about, since the JSON parser is reporting an error at "line 1 column 1 (char 0)", which does not correspond to the position of `___`.

Comment: great ! thanks so much guys :) so it outputs a string in the format '{\n  "question" : {\n    "0cGufvFVCR" : {\n      "answer" : 100,\n      "date" : "Mar 26, 2020",\n      "email" :

Comment: yes, exactly the ___ was a placeholder to protect the data :~)

Comment: I would have bet your string would be starting with `"\ufeff{\n..."` (or at least something similar). If it actually starts with `"{\n...`, no idea.

Comment: There is a strange symbol that holds a question mark, maybe this is my computers interpretation of ufeff ... Would you know what it means if that is the case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark